# Can I use SharePoint Farm backups in differential mode at the same time as using DPM using differential snapshots to backup the content databases?

Tags: backup, server-farm

Using SharePoint 2010.

My question is in the title.  I have a SharePoint farm that I am using the SharePoint Farm backup to backup the entire farm each Saturday, and a differential backup every other day of the week.  I want to also use DPM to backup the content databases with a full backup and differential snapshots being taken every 4 hours.

Will there be any conflict between the differential backups by SharePoint and the differential backups by DPM?  I don't want there to be an issue where a transaction log gets truncated by one of the two methods and the other method loses transactions in its backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly take full and differential backups of SharePoint databases using DPM and a separate SQL maintenance job. But you must ensure that both of them do not occur at the same time.

Another thing is the location where DPM saves the data should be different from the SQL Server Maintenance job based exported location. This way you ensure that all differential backups for the same database gets saved on different locations , thereby having the option restoring the backups from the latest one (either DPM or SQL Job) based on whichever took the last diff backup in case of any disaster.